# Magento set value of dropdown attribute via SOAP v2 API

Tags: soap-api-v2, dropdown-attribute

As the title says, I'm trying to set/modify the value of a drop down type attribute through the SOAP v2 API.  Below is the latest bit of code that I'm working with:

```
$update_data = array (
    'additional_attributes' => array (
        'multi_data' => array (
            array ('key' => 'ship_separately', 'value' => array ('0' => '1'))
        ),
        'single_data' => array (
            array ('key' => 'ship_width', 'value' => '14'),
            array ('key' => 'ship_length', 'value' => '24'),
            array ('key' => 'ship_height', 'value' => '12'),
            //array ('key' => 'ship_separately', 'value' => 'Yes')
        )
    )
);

$update = $proxy->catalogProductUpdate($sessionId, 'MySKU', $update_data, NULL, 'sku');
```

The 'single_data' (just simple name/value pairs) attributes update fine.  As you can see, I also tried to update the 'ship_separetely' using the 'single_data' array...to no avail.  Google and StackExchange put me on the path of the 'multi_data' array, but finding documentation on it is virtually impossible.  I think I have the syntax correct because the API isn't throwing an exception and it is updating the 'single_data' attributes, but won't update the drop down value. It is a simple yes/no drop down, so I've tried setting the value to both 'Yes' and '1', but it doesn't change.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might seem stupid but have you tried setting it to `1` or `true` without the quotes?

Comment: Not stupid at all; I'm hoping it is something simple like that.  Just gave it a shot, but no luck.  No error, but no update either.  Thanks!

Comment: In your code, you have misspelled `separately`, that probably doesn't help

Comment: Yeah, I caught that while I was making this post and thought that was it.  Changed it to the proper spelling and tried, but that didn't work either.  I just forgot to change it in the post.  Changed now.

Comment: I have just tested myself and `'1'` works perfect for me. Are you sure you got the name right? If it's been newly created, you will need to Flush Magento cache or else it won't know the field exists.

Comment: I can only guess that I didn't try '1' as my value.  Read this numerous times; searched the web, and no answer because it was like no one else had this issue.  Decided to start from scratch, and setting the value to '1' worked perfectly.  It wasn't a new attribute, so it had to be my mistake.  Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else is having a bad day like me, the solution was to set the value to '1', but not in a 'multi_data' array...

```
$update_data = array (
    'additional_attributes' => array (
        'single_data' => array (
            array ('key' => 'ship_width', 'value' => '14'),
            array ('key' => 'ship_length', 'value' => '24'),
            array ('key' => 'ship_height', 'value' => '12'),
            array ('key' => 'ship_separately', 'value' => '1')
        )
    )
);

$update = $proxy->catalogProductUpdate($sessionId, 'MySKU', $update_data, NULL, 'sku');
```

Many thanks to Mayers

Comment: Odd, because in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2` I can't see any different between the two. But glad it worked for you :)